# Why there is no good algorithm to buffer the stack data structure using hard disk while queue has?

Tags: algorithm, stack, depth-first-search, analysis

We can divide a queue into two parts: first half for deque and the other for enqueue, then we can store the first half on hard disk while the other on memory. By doing so we can accelerate the enqueue operation and create a very large queue compared to a queue which is all stored in memory for computing.

From a book it says there is no analogical idea for stack data structure, but without telling me why. So, why we won't buffer a stack using hard disk? What are the drawbacks doing so? Is it about the time-complexity, or some logical reasons so that we cannot even if we want? Thanks in advance.

Not sure about whether this is relative but my context is about graph searching-algorithm where the `push` operation occurs much more frequently than `pop` operation during the exploration phase and building the stack, i.e. using in Depth First Search.

Comment: I don't think there's quite enough information in the question to understand exactly what the book is describing. Can you provide a reference, and perhaps flesh out what the book describes?

Comment: @PaulHankin: It's not written in English. While the part is: it provides an disk-version of BFS and the idea of this BFS_disk algorithm is as my post described, then in another section of DFS it just mentioned that there is no good algorithm to utilize the disk space in case of the size of stack become extremely large than memory can hold similar to what just did in BFS section.

Comment: May I ask you that what information you want? So I can try my best to translate it into English and edit my questoin.

Comment: Enough that the "analogical idea" makes sense. Storing half the data on disk is not the idea I think, but rather some details of how pushes and pops work, and how the files are managed on disk.

Comment: @PaulHankin: The idea of BFS_disk in the book is described as: When reading from queue, first check that whether the queue_disk is empty, if so then move content of queue_mem to queue_disk and read again; when writing, first write to queue_mem and check it is not full before writing, if it's full then move that into queue_disk first. What I meant by "two half" are queue_mem and queue_disk. I thought my description is much concise than this description, since we can view "queue_disk + queue_mem" as a single queue, one for reading and one for writing.

Comment: The details are still underspecified, but the problem with implementing a stack like this is that reads and writes interfere -- if you read a block from disk to pop some of it, you might have to discard it (or write it back to disk) if more pushes happen. The details matter a lot here, so it's hard to answer convincingly.

Comment: Disk is a memory. You can always use disk when you want. In your case, when your stack grows too much (using a memory threshold), write part of it to disk to free some ram... What's wrong with this ?

Comment: I think what the book is after is that in a stack both push and pop work on the same end of the data structure, so you cannot do the pops from disk and the pushes to memory. However, although that's true it seems like a silly argument to me. You could still store the "bottom half" of the stack to disk. Which is arguably even better than the queue case because that data really is not going to be needed until the top half of the stack has been handled.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Yes that's my question, the book says there is no efficient algorithm for stack compared to queue, I just want to confirm whether this is correct and if so why,

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele: I'm totally agreed with you, and that's what I thought before asking this, but I just want to confirm because I'm not expert in this field. Yes I thought it would even work better than the case for stack, since both ends are on memory, i.e. both accelerated.

Comment: I think his argument is at least very strange. But as I don't have access to the text, I can't say more than: seems a silly argument.